# Grouping multiple selects within a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table Supplier with two columns, TotalStock and Date.  I'm trying to write a single query that will give me stock totals by week / month / year for a list of suppliers.

So results will look like this..

```
SUPPLIER  WEEK MONTH YEAR
SupplierA 50   100   2000
SupplierB 60   150   2500
SupplierC 15   25    200
```

So far I've been playing around with multiple selects but I can't get any further than this:

```
SELECT Supplier,
    (
    SELECT      Sum(TotalStock)
    FROM        StockBreakdown
    WHERE       Date >= '2014-5-12'
    GROUP BY    Supplier
    ) AS StockThisWeek,
    (
    SELECT      Sum(TotalStock)
    FROM        StockBreakdown
    WHERE       Date >= '2014-5-1'
    GROUP BY    Supplier
    ) AS StockThisMonth,
    (
    SELECT      Sum(TotalStock)
    FROM        StockBreakdown
    WHERE       Date >= '2014-1-1'
    GROUP BY    Supplier
    ) AS StockThisYear
```

This query throws an error as each individual grouping returns multiple results.  I feel that I'm close to the solution but can't work out where to go

Comment: try to use to join the querry'S

Comment: Where do you get Supplier names? Is there a table related with this one with Supplier data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use subqueries to achieve what you want :

```
SELECT Supplier
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= CAST('2014-05-12' as DATE) THEN TotalStock END) AS StockThisWeek
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= CAST('2014-05-01' as DATE) THEN TotalStock END) AS StockThisMonth
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= CAST('2014-01-01' as DATE) THEN TotalStock END) AS StockThisYear
FROM  StockBreakdown
GROUP BY Supplier
```

Comment: this works thanks, would there be much difference in performance in using this against @Thorsten Dittmar answer?

Comment: @lisburnite : Glad to help you!Of course there is a difference in performance. His query is more complicated and it is not needed here at all (unless you are using indexes and your table is very large).

Comment: @lisburnite : Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make the selects for the columns return only a single result. You could try this (not tested currently):

```
SELECT Supplier,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 StockThisWeek FROM
    (
       SELECT      Supplier, Sum(TotalStock) AS StockThisWeek
       FROM        StockBreakdown
       WHERE       Date >= '2014-5-12'
       GROUP BY    Supplier
    ) tmp1
    WHERE tmp1.Supplier = Supplier 
) AS StockThisWeek,

(
    SELECT TOP 1 StockThisMonth FROM
    (
       SELECT      Supplier, Sum(TotalStock) AS StockThisMonth
       FROM        StockBreakdown
       WHERE       Date >= '2014-5-1'
       GROUP BY    Supplier
    ) tmp2
    WHERE tmp2.Supplier = Supplier 
) AS StockThisMonth, 

...
```

This selects the supplier and then tries to create two columns `StockThisWeek` and `StockThisMonth` by selecting the first entry from the select you created before. As through the `GROUP BY` there should only be one entry per supplier, so you don't lose and data.

Comment: Thanks, this should work, however I used @Notulysses solution below